# Creating a Horizontal list of smaller Editor windows in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm about to start playing around with writing a VSCode extension. There are a ton of tutorials out there but I'm already overwhelmed on how to approach the idea that I have.

Essentially I would like to implement a helper that provides me with a list of editable snippets in the main editor view.

```
created_at: 2020-04-30
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Text goes here                                               |
|                                                               |
|                                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+

created_at: 2020-04-28
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  More text goes here                                          |
|                                                               |
|                                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In addition I would need a button (and or shortcut) to create new empty text boxes on the top for this.

I have a vague idea on how to serialize this into a format and store it as a file somewhere but I'm not sure on how to implement the UI.

I was thinking about using a [custom editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) but am thinking that this might be a little overkill. Ideally there was a way to have a list of text boxes in one view that can be expanded and collapsed (kind of like the settings window).

Answer (score 0):

Without more details and examples about what you are trying to do, a distinct answer is difficult.

I recently walked down the path you are thinking about.  I found it very useful, to start a git repo, and just start building documentation about your idea and add all the links and examples you can find.  Surf the extension marketplace to find examples of what you want to do (and get more ideas), put all that content in your repo (copy or direct reference).  Then I spent time testing and working through many of the examples here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples

Learning how to clone the git for an extension, run and debug the different features allowed me to reverse engineer the functionality I needed.

Starting with something simple, like a command from the pallete, to open an editor with some text might get you moving in the right direction.

Something like this example extension with some extra input boxes might be what you need:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/virtual-document-sample

If you require a more robust interface for user input/output, the webview may be your ultimate goal:
- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webview-sample